# Spark - Create a DataFrame from a list of Rows generated in a loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a loop which generates rows in each iteration. My goal is to create a dataframe, with a given schema, that contents just those rows. I have in mind a set of steps to follow, but I am not able to add a new `Row` to a `List[Row]` in each loop iteration

I am trying the following approach:

```
var listOfRows = List[Row]()

val dfToExtractValues: DataFrame = ???

dfToExtractValues.foreach { x => 

    //Not really important how to generate here the variables
    //So to simplify all the rows will have the same values

    var col1 = "firstCol"
    var col2 = "secondCol"  
    var col3 = "thirdCol"

    val newRow =  RowFactory.create(col1,col2,col3)

    //This step I am not able to do
    //listOfRows += newRow        -> Just for strings
    //listOfRows.add(newRow)      -> This add doesnt exist, it is a addString
    //listOfRows.aggregate(1)(newRow)       -> This is not how aggreage works...
}


val rdd = sc.makeRDD[RDD](listOfRows)   

val dfWithNewRows = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, myOriginalDF.schema)
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, or what could I change in my approach to generate a dataframe from the rows I'm generating?

Maybe there is a better way to collect the Rows instead of List[Row]. But then I need to convert that other type of collection into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong

**Closures**:

First of all it looks like you skipped over [*Understanding Closures*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) in the Programming Guide. Any attempt to modify variables passed with closure is futile. All you can do is modify a copy and changes won't be reflected globally.

**Variable doesn't make object mutable:**

Following

```
var listOfRows = List[Row]()
```

creates a variable. Assigned `List` is as immutable as it was. If it wasn't in the Spark context you could create a new `List` and reassign:

```
listOfRows = newRow :: listOfRows
```

Note that we perpend not append - you don't want to append to the list in a loop.

Variables with immutable objects are useful, when you want to share data (it is common pattern in Akka for example), but don't have many applications in Spark.

**Keep things distributed:**

Finally never fetch data to the driver just to distribute it again. You should also avoid unnecessary conversions between `RDDs` and `DataFrames`. It is best to use `DataFrame` operators all the way:

```
dfToExtractValues.select(...)
```

but if you need something more complex `map`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

dfToExtractValues.map(x => ...)(RowEncoder(schema))
```